MDC logging for C programs?
Is a good idea/practice to generate MDC like logs from a C structured program?. To be more precise this would be printing to console or file a JSON format that includes context data within a mdc field. These logs are to be ingested from an ELK stack.
My hypothesis is that it is not recommended, but I want to find counter arguments to challenge my hypothesis against so I can finally defend it in front of the "Jury".
Why I do believe is not a good Idea?

It is met for Java framework
From a C program that needs to be very efficient and achieve very low latencies (< 10 ms) , the JSON format should be an unnecessary overhead that will have a cost.

Regards

Since MDC is a java implementation, you would need to implement it by yourself I guess? From what I read MDC provides a way to enrich logs with a static class, when the interface for the is restricted and more info might be needed. If you write the program from scratch, will this actually be a problem or do you need to modify an existing program?
